# How to batch rename files in windows removing everything from them but set of listed strings?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have went through a lot of guides for it, but havent found a way to do something similar to lets say turn all files in folder, like these files:

- djhwu4s_cat_ruhg29.png
- 397y_dog_j0929_ej93.png
- 8yhh_owl.png

into these:

- _cat.png
- _dog.png
- _owl.png

So basically removing everything from file names but a list of predefined strings i am searching for. In example above i would define list as "_cat", "_dog", "_owl". I know that each file will have only one of these variables, and there will be only one file with each of them in folder.

Will appreciate any tips on how to achieve that. Thanks in advance!

edit:
Here is what i came up with (with stuff i can understund) and what seems to be working fine now.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set v1=_cat-cat
set v2=_cat-owl
set v3=_cat
set v4=_dog
set v5=_owl
set v6=_horse

FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,6) DO ( 
    rem echo %%a
    rem echo !v%%a!
    FOR /f %%f in ('dir /b /a:-D *!v%%a!.*') DO (
    REN %%f !v%%a!.*
    )
    FOR /f %%f in ('dir /b /a:-D *!v%%a!_*.*') DO (
    REN %%f !v%%a!.*
    )
)

rem using two passes of this simpler code i can grasp and understund with dot and with underscore
rem after constructed variables value i make sure cat-cat is not recognised as and renamed to cat
rem no matter if im getting file with that variable as the last string before extension or another underscore
rem Gonna test it in combat now
```

For some reason this stuff doesnt work with files containing spaces and characters like:
"ab’c efg_dog.png"

```
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,36) DO ( 
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /b /l /a:-D *!v%%a!.*') DO (
REN "%%f" "!v%%a!.*"
)
FOR /f %%f in ('dir /b /l /a:-D *!v%%a!_*.*') DO (
REN "%%f" "!v%%a!.*"
)
)
```

After further testing i have realised the problem starts with the %%f, and not the REN function as i thought. echo %%f before ren gives just the first part of the name to the first space, hence the REN function cant find the file. In case of "ab’c efg_dog.png" after finding the file with dir, the %%f becomes just "ab’c".

edit: After more tests and experiments and adding those "delims" to the code, the echo now shows proper, full names to be renamed, but it replaces that weird ’ character with ' for the REN command and thats why it still cant find the file to rename.

```
FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,36) DO ( 
FOR /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /l /a:-D *!v%%a!.*') DO (
echo %%f
echo REN "%%f" "!v%%a!.*"
)
FOR /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /l /a:-D *!v%%a!_*.*') DO (
echo %%f
echo REN "%%f" "!v%%a!.*"
)
)
```

Comment: String handling in batch files is never fun, consider using PowerShell?

Comment: Where will the list of predefined strings be?

Comment: It could be within the script itself - i dont expect the list to change (often if whatsoever)

Comment: Anders, it could be anything that i can drop into folder and execute to rename like this.

Comment: Thanks everyone! After hours spent googling every single part of suggested codes i have managed to make something that works for my purposes. It might not be elegant, but if I have a choice to use things i understund and can edit/troubleshoot and something super cool that i do not understund i prefer the non-elegant, but understundable approach. I am superhappy now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following setting for the directory is a name
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

PUSHD "%sourcedir%"

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ('dir /b /a-d "*_*" 2^nul ^|findstr /v /b "_"') DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=2delims=_." %%y IN ("%%e") DO ECHO REN "%%e" "_%%y%%~xe"
)

POPD

GOTO :EOF
```

For lack of examples, here's a start.

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Process the list of filenames that match `*_*`; find those names that do not start `_`, pick the second string between the delimiters `_` and `.` and rename using that string (in `%%y`), prefixed by `_` and appended with the original extension.

The `ren` command is simply `echo`ed to the screen for verification. When happy, remove the `echo` before the `ren` to actually execute the rename.

Comment: Thanks Magoo and Mofi! I will be investigating whats what in these proposed examples and hopefully will get a grip. :)

Comment: Magoo, do you know a way to make the %%f kind of variable not replace special characters that are being "fed" into it? Talking about change of for example that weird apostrophe  ’ character with straight apostrophe '

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Such characters are rendered differently depending on your code page and font. For me, It's displayed as `Æ`. I've tried a filename using that string - it works as advertised for the name `"ab’c efg_dog.png"`, renaming it to `_dog.png`

Comment: Sorry i dont get those tokens yet so i dont understund your code. The thing is i cant rely on naming order and construction anymore (crazy files to work with). Hence i tried to make a code that will search for particular variable like "_dog" then for "_horse" and so on in dir and then take the resulting file and rename it to such variable+extension. And it works with everything so far, other than file with this ’ curly apostrophe. Echo in my last code's version returns the correct file name but with straight apostrophe for some reason and i am now searching for a way to to correct that. :S

Comment: And for some reason when i am using the very same dir command that i have in batch, but in cmd console, it returns name with correct, curly apostrophe. Yet when exectued with batch, echo returns straight apostrophe in filename :S

Comment: Ha! I think adding chcp 65001 on top of the batch file fixes this problem. :) batch couldnt "type" the curly apostrophe with command, only could take it from real filename when it was there (hence i was getting curly apostrophe with dir command, yet when it was dynamically created by batch script from %%f variable, it was turned into straight apostrophe.